# Twins. Who are they?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You can find both in Istanbul, but none in water
>   They are the same size, but one of them is smaller
>
> In some fields they can cause confusion
>   But if one grows, it will break the illusion
>
> Different names, if called with the tone
>   But probably the same, if carved in stone

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/childrens-riddle

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is it

> A capital i (I) and a lower case l (L)?

You can find both in Istanbul, but none in water

> Both letters are in **I**stanbu**l**, but neither in water

They are same size, but one of them is smaller

> They are both full height, but the capital I is a bit smaller (Thanks @jwfrench !).

In some fields they can cause confusion

> They look very similar in a lot of fonts

But if one grows, it will break illusion

> If the lower case l is capitalized it no longer looks similar.

Different names, if called with the tone

> Obviously called different and have different sounds

But probably same, if carved in the stone

> A bit of a stretch here: because they look similar in text?

Comment: I don't know who was faster because it shows same time(maybe you guys are twins?!). But your explanation of third line is better.

Comment: @Traxo My interpretation of the third line was actually what helped me to find the solution: there aren't many letters which appear in both "Istanbul" and "some fields". But I don't at all grudge PHP the tick: after all, I've got more than enough rep already ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor Actually I wasn't paying attention to word `fields`, now I see I should have :). I actually struggled to make that line **less obvious** but still keep rhyme! When you know solution, it's kinda hard to tell which line is most obvious, so thanks, I value your feedback.

Comment: Mostly correct!
One of them being smaller refers to an uppercase [i] being slightly *shorter* than a lowercase [L] though, not thinner.
And yes, the last part is not a stretch – it refers again to them being visually similar in contrast to their pronunciation (even though *technically* stone carvings of the letters would likely employ distinctions such as serifs...)

Comment: These answers are the twins in the riddle. XD

Answer (score 13):

I think they are

> capital `I` and lower-case `l`: "twins" because I and l are almost identical.

*You can find both in Istanbul, but none in water*

> Both appear is **I**stanbu**l**, but neither in the word "water". (Actually, technically, in Turkish the capital I in Istanbul has a dot, **İstanbul**, so the two letters are distinguishable. You shouldn't have chosen a Turkish word as your example ;-) )

*They are same size, but one of them is smaller*

> I and l look almost identical in many fonts, but one is lower-case and the other is upper-case, and they may differ slightly in size even when almost identical.

*In some fields they can cause confusion*

> Both letters appear in the word "f**i**e**l**ds", and their similarity can certainly cause confusion.

*But if one grows, it will break illusion*

> Turning the lower-case i in "illusion" into a capital would break the word by giving it an apparent triple l (or triple I).

*Different names, if called with the tone*

> When pronouncing them aloud, I and l certainly sound very different ...

*But probably same, if carved in the stone*

> ... but they look pretty much the same in writing.

Comment: Wow, I guess it comes down to who gets the explanation correct first

Comment: @bg6471 I *just* managed to do it first, but the edit history doesn't show that because PHP shadow-edited but your comment prevented me from shadow-editing :-/

Comment: I don't care, you can take credit if you really want it. I am just glad that I was able to get an answer on a puzzle here

Comment: Sorry, I feel really bad now. I'll keep that in mind for future.

Comment: @PartyHatPanda No, you get credit as well :-) It's clear that we both solved it independently, after all.

Comment: I actually thought the last line was referring to how it would be read aloud as per the line above. If it's in stone, I'm guessing it's a reference to Roman numerals and they both would be pronounced as the ancient Roman word for "one" would be

Comment: I think "breaking illusion" refers to the fact that if you make the "i" uppercase, it will look like the word has 3 lowercase "L"s in a row.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Good one, thanks! (I'd actually noticed the "illusion" thing, but forgot it by the time I came to type up my explanation.)

Comment: Referencing the actual word 'illusion' gets closed to a fun double meaning, but I think because the riddle is referring specifically to an uppercase [i] and lowercase [L], thinking about a lowercase [i] growing is a red herring. It actually refers to the lowercase [L] becoming an uppercase [L] so that it no longer looks the same as the uppercase [i].

Comment: Would you like the bounty now or in a couple of days? :)

Comment: @MrPie I don't mind :-) Thank you very much, by the way! I just noticed today that you'd placed a bounty on this for me.